# Autolayout not working on centerX- centerY

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add constraint manually; I am having the following error every time the code tries to add the centerX and centerY constraints:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint
>   reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's
>   illegal. constraint:
>   (active)> view:>'

I checked multiple questions from before but nothing helped :/

Thank you[image: !My code[1]]

**CODE**

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
[cell.contentView addSubview:title];
title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                    constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:nil
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                    constant:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/8];
NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewWidthtConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:imageView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewCenterXConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:[imageView superview]
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewCenterYConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                  constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                  toItem:[imageView superview]
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:0];
[imageView addConstraint:imageViewHeightConstraint];
[imageView addConstraint:imageViewWidthtConstraint];
[imageView addConstraint:imageViewCenterXConstraint];
[imageView addConstraint:imageViewCenterYConstraint];
```

Comment: is it possible for you to do in the storyboard ? or it must be hard coded...

Comment: it can't be done in storyboard since I need it to be dynamic!

Comment: please post your code as text, not as picture.

Comment: Try removing the `addConstraint` lines and add `.active = YES` after each instantiation of the constraint. Also change `[image superview]` for `cell`

Comment: @Swinny89 it worked! thanks

Comment: No problem, i've added it as an answer so you can mark it as the accepted answer for other people having the same issue

Comment: @KingT. If you need it to be dynamic, how about set initial values in the storyboard, ctrl + drag the autolayout outlet and change the outlet itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `addConstraint` lines and add `.active = YES` after each instantiation of the constraint. Also change `[image superview]` for `cell`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add centerX and centerY constraint to superview of imageView, instead to imageView

```
[cell.contentView addConstraint:imageViewCenterXConstraint]; 
[cell.contentView addConstraint:imageViewCenterYConstraint];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this after add constraint to UIImageView.

For Objective C

```
[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

For Swift

```
cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Please try this first, give constraint first, then after add you imageView to cell contentView.

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you use:

```
imageView.center = cell.center
```

It should center your image in cell.

Comment: The question is specifically asking for an auto layout solution.